# phonegap apps internet access problem. How to solve it?

Tags: html, phonegap

I made a android apps by the help of online phonegap builder.I use here html css javascript.But this apps are not take any internet connection.It's doesn't want any internet access permisson. How can i solve it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the tour and read through [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck.

Answer (score 0):

use **whitelist plugin**  `cordova-plugin-whitelist`

and add this to your config.xml:

```
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<allow-intent href="*" />
<access origin="*" />
```

and add in index.html this :

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```